# How to find the shortest cycle containing two specific nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to find the shortest cycle for each $v$ vertex in an undirected graph with positive weights that contains $v$ and a fixed $u$ node. What is the cheepest way to do so?

Edit: The notion of cycle is very confusing. In the sense of the question, a cycle is a closed trail where edges are not repeated.

Comment: My graphs are edge-weighted and undirected. Weighting has not been mentioned in the description, so I have updated it. Please, report this trivial algorithm.

Comment: You could use something like [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: But how? Are the two shortest paths between $u$ and $v$ independent?

Comment: No, there are no negative weights.

Comment: @frabala Could you please detail how to perform this trivial procedure?

Comment: I haven't found the time to check it thoroughly but my idea was to run Dijkstra with $u$ as the source node, which gives you all shortest paths from $u$ to the rest of the nodes. I have the impression that by following such a path forwards and then backwards (since the graph is undirected), you get your result. It's a cycle that contains the two nodes and (still, to be checked) it's the shortest such cycle.

Comment: @frabala Meanwhile I found a page, where similar results are introduced (https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/44244). If we take a non-tree edge $(v,x)$, then we have to provide the shortest paths from $x$ to $u$ and from $v$ to $u$. However, this pair of paths does not form a cycle if the lowest common ancestor of $v$ and $x$, LCA($v,x$), preceeds $u$. In this case, only a cycle $v$-LCA($v,x$)-$x$ is found.

Comment: @Roli That link regards simple cycles. Are you looking for *simple* cycles as well? If yes, then my solution above doesn't apply. Please give all necessary information of the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the two paths between $u$ and $v$ should be edge-disjoint (but not necessarily node-disjoint). And what is the situation in this case?

Comment: I will have to think about this. Meanwhile I am not seeing how this would be trivial, even if restricted to instances where the graph is undirected and all edges  have the same unit length. Dijkstra will not necessarily return a *cycle*--i.e., two paths that are *vertex-disjoint* except at their endpoints $u$ and $v$, which is what the OP wants

Comment: @Mike, indeed Dijkstra returns paths, but one can use those paths to form cycles. *Without* the condition in the problem definition that the desired cycle must cross edges *uniquely*, one can go back and forth over the shortest *path* and thus trivially make a (shortest) cycle.

Comment: @frabala But a cycle containing two fixed nodes $u$ and $v$? Two paths that cross will make cycles but not necessarily one containing $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Meanwhile if people here know how to solve the problem then why didn't anyone put it down as an answer??

Comment: @frabala My question has been edited.

Comment: @Roli I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm editing my answer, because it was totally wrong.

I came across [Suurballe's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm), which solves the problem for two fixed nodes $u$ and $v$. In your question, you want to find the shortest simple cycle between a fixed $u$ and any other node $v$. Then, you can run Suubralle's algorithm for the fixed $u$ and every $v$.

The first part of the algorithm (running Dijkstra for the first time) will always give you the same result. So, you can save some time by running this part only once and then running the rest of the algorithm for each $v$ separately.